# Add a menu button on control bar in videojs

Tags: video.js

Hi I am using videojs player framework version 5.2.4.

I am trying to add a custom button in control bar menu. I tried code given here [add item in control bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550897/videojs-4-0-plugin-how-to-properly-add-items-to-the-controlbar/)

But it seems that our version of video js is causing a problem in calling functions.

Is there any help for current version of video js? Also I want it to show/hide automatically as control bar hide and show.

Please help.

Comment: Check the docs http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/components.html

Comment: I have tried this link before. It showing adding videojs component but i need to add my own control in control bar menu. As mentioned above I am using 5.2.4 version of videojs.